# No me sale el ejercicio exacto de quiniela aleatoria

Tags: java

El ejercicio

```
/*
4) Programa que imprima una quiniela aleatoria, quince filas con 1, X ó 2, y que aparezcan en sus respectivas
*/
```

Lo que debe Imprimir

```
/*
Partido  1: |1| | |
Partido  2: | |X| |
Partido  3: |1| | |
Partido  4: | |X| |
Partido  5: | | |2|
Partido  6: | |X| |
Partido  7: | | |2|
Partido  8: | | |2|
Partido  9: | | |2|
Partido 10: | |X| |
Partido 11: | |X| |
Partido 12: |1| | |
Partido 13: |1| | |
Partido 14: | |X| |
Partido 15: | | |2|
 */
```

Lo que imprime puede ser  aleatorio por lo que puede cambiar de posición el partido 1  a la x o la dependiendo.

Lo que me imprime.

```
/*
Partido 1    | | |2|
Partido 2    |1| | |
Partido 3    | |X| |
Partido 4    |1| | |
Partido 5    |1| | |
Partido 6    | |X| |
Partido 7    | | |2|
Partido 8    | | |2|
Partido 9    |1| | |
Partido 10    | |X| |
Partido 11    | | |2|
Partido 12    | | |2|
Partido 13    |1| | |
Partido 14    |1| | |
Partido 15    | |X| |
*/
```

Los dos puntos da igual que este o no pero quiero que las columnas salga rectas.

Mi codigo.

```
/*
4) Programa que imprima una quiniela aleatoria, quince filas con 1, X ó 2, y que aparezcan en sus respectivas
columnas. P.Ej.: 
Partido  1: |1| | |
Partido  2: | |X| |
Partido  3: |1| | |
Partido  4: | |X| |
Partido  5: | | |2|
Partido  6: | |X| |
Partido  7: | | |2|
Partido  8: | | |2|
Partido  9: | | |2|
Partido 10: | |X| |
Partido 11: | |X| |
Partido 12: |1| | |
Partido 13: |1| | |
Partido 14: | |X| |
Partido 15: | | |2|
 */
package examen1Tr;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class Ejercicio4 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numAletorio;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 15) {
            numAletorio = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
            i++;

            if (numAletorio == 1) {
                System.out.println("Partido " + i + "    |1| | |");
            } else if (numAletorio == 2) {
                System.out.println("Partido " + i + "    | |X| |");
            } else if (numAletorio == 3) {
                System.out.println("Partido " + i + "    | | |2|");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

4. Programa que imprima una quiniela aleatoria, quince filas con 1, X ó 2, y que aparezcan en sus respectivas.
   Lo he intentado con un if pero nada no me sale. E estado buscado información de como hacerlo pero nada de nada no lo e podido encontrar. Me e estado rompiendo la cabeza y al final nada yo mientras estare intentándolo en una clase aparte para ver las diferencias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de que no estén alineados se da por los números del 1 al 9 que son de un solo caracter. Si te fijas en la salida están los 2 puntos que van después del número alineados y de ahí que todo lo demás hacia la derecha también lo esté.

Para corregirlo lo puedes hacer de dos maneras. Con `if`s si `i` es menor que 10 metes un espacio antes del número. La otra opción es con el método `String.format`:

```
String.format("%1$2s", i) //Rellena con espacios hasta completar 2 caracteres
```

Al final los `if`s de tu código quedarían así:

```
if (numAletorio == 1) {
    System.out.println("Partido " + String.format("%1$2s", i) + ": |1| | |");
} else if (numAletorio == 2) {
    System.out.println("Partido " + String.format("%1$2s", i) + ": | |X| |");
} else if (numAletorio == 3) {
    System.out.println("Partido " + String.format("%1$2s", i) + ": | | |2|");
}
```

Comment: voy a mirarlo ahora mismo

Answer (score 1):

no te sale bien por la cantidad de caracteres que utilizas en las filas con un numero mayor a 10.
He modificado un poco tu codigo para que añada un pequeño espacio si el numero es menor de 10.
Es probable que la sintaxis no sea del todo correcta ya que no programo en java pero la idea está ahi.

```
while (i < 15) {
            numAletorio = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
            i++;

            string espacio = "";
            if(i < 10)
              espacio = " "; 

            if (numAletorio == 1) {
                System.out.println("Partido " + espacio + i + "    |1| | |");
            } else if (numAletorio == 2) {
                System.out.println("Partido " + espacio + i + "    | |X| |");
            } else if (numAletorio == 3) {
                System.out.println("Partido " + espacio + i + "    | | |2|");
            }

        }
```

Comment: voy a mirarlo ahora mismo

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una manera facil y sencilla seria  asi.

```
/*
4) Programa que imprima una quiniela aleatoria, quince filas con 1, X ó 2, y que aparezcan en sus respectivas
columnas. P.Ej.: 
Partido  1: |1| | |
Partido  2: | |X| |
Partido  3: |1| | |
Partido  4: | |X| |
Partido  5: | | |2|
Partido  6: | |X| |
Partido  7: | | |2|
Partido  8: | | |2|
Partido  9: | | |2|
Partido 10: | |X| |
Partido 11: | |X| |
Partido 12: |1| | |
Partido 13: |1| | |
Partido 14: | |X| |
Partido 15: | | |2|
 */
package examen1Tr;

/**
 *
 * @author javie
 */
public class Ejercicio4_V2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numAletorio;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 15) {
            numAletorio = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
            i++;
            if (i <= 9) {
                if (numAletorio == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Partido " + i + " :  |1| | |");
                } else if (numAletorio == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Partido " + i + " :  | |X| |");
                } else if (numAletorio == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Partido " + i + " :  | | |2|");
                }
            } else {
                if (numAletorio == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Partido " + i + ":  |1| | |");
                } else if (numAletorio == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Partido " + i + ":  | |X| |");
                } else if (numAletorio == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Partido " + i + ":  | | |2|");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El creado varias condiciones donde compruebo y ambas idea tanto la de glen sandoval y la de ivanpotato esta bien esperare unos días a que voten a ver cual de las dos respuesta esta mejor y le doy el check de correcto